# RefTeX not finding `label={name}` in custom environment

Tags: cross-referencing, reftex

I defined a new `tcolorbox` based floating environment named `riquadro`, and I want RefTeX to find the label I insert using `label={name}` option.

From the documentation of `reftex-label-regexps` it seems the keyval style format should be recognised by default, but no label of this type appears when I try to run `reftex-reference` (with `C-c )`).

I also set up

```
 (reftex-add-label-environments
   '(("riquadro" ?a "riq:" nil caption ("riquadro")))
```

but this seems to have no effect.

Maybe I have to declare the new environment and tell RefTeX to look for its label, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Which Emacs version are you using?

Comment: GNU Emacs 28.0.50.
AUCTeX 12.3.1

Comment: I realised the problem is that `reftex-label-regexps` looks for keyval labels only within specific environments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior of `reftex-label-regexps` was changed with Emacs version 27: RefTeX now looks for the `label` key in the optional argument of given environments; others are ignored.  The docstring says:

> `reftex-label-regexps` is a variable defined in ‘reftex-vars.el’. Its
> value is [...]
>
> Documentation:
> List of regexps matching `\label` definitions. The
> default value matches usual `\label{...}` definitions and keyval style
> `[..., label = {...}, ...]` label definitions.  The regexp for keyval
> style explicitly looks for environments provided by the packages
> "listings" ("lstlisting"), "beamer" ("frame"), "breqn" ("dmath",
> "dseries", "dgroup", "darray") and the macro "\ctable" provided by the
> package of the same name.
>
> It is assumed that the regexp group 1 matches the label text, so you
> have to define it using `\(?1:...\)` when adding new regexps.

For your custom environment, you can use the `customize` interface to add an entry or put something like this in your init file:

```el
(with-eval-after-load "reftex-vars"
  (add-to-list 'reftex-label-regexps
               (concat
                "\\\\begin[[:space:]]*{riquadro}[[:space:]]*"
                ;; Match the opening [ and the following chars
                "\\[[^][]*"
                ;; Allow nested levels of chars enclosed in braces
                "\\(?:{[^}{]*"
                  "\\(?:{[^}{]*"
                    "\\(?:{[^}{]*}[^}{]*\\)*"
                  "}[^}{]*\\)*"
                "}[^][]*\\)*"
                ;; Match the label key
                "\\<label[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*"
                ;; Match the label value; braces around the value are
                ;; optional.
                "{?\\(?1:[^] ,}\r\n\t%]+\\)"
                ;; We are done.  Just search until the next closing bracket
                "[^]]*\\]")
               t))
```

OTOH, AUCTeX has a style file for `tcolorbox` which is able to parse and process user defined environments.  It should contain some code to make this addition automatically.