# RefTeX and tcbnewtheorem

Tags: tcolorbox, theorems, reftex

I'd like for RefTeX to know about labels defined by tcbtheorem environments. Here's an example where RefTeX does not find the relevant label...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}{}{thm}
\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}{Important theorem}{foobar}
  Test of theorem.
\end{theorem}

Reference to theorem: \ref{thm:foobar}.

\end{document}
```

The most similar question I can find is [RefTeX not finding `label={name}` in custom environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/584395/reftex-not-finding-label-name-in-custom-environment), but it doesn't quite answer the question for me.

Answer (score 1):

RefTeX is not able to parse the label prefix argument defined in `\newtcbtheorem` and then add it to the label definition `foobar` so you can reference `thm:foobar`.  If you can skip the prefix and add it manually to each label definition, you probably can use the technique described in RefTeX manual under [15 Problems and Work-arounds](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/reftex.html#Problems-and-Work_002dArounds) and do something like this in your init file:

```el
(setq reftex-label-alist
      '(("\\begin{theorem}{}{*}" ?o "thm:" "~\\ref{%s}" 3)))
```

This way, RefTeX should be able to detect your label definition and support referencing it.